# R add column that sums the mean of three scores

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data.frame:

```
scoreA    scoreB    scoreC
  50        60        70
 ...       ...       ...
```

I want to add a colum such that:

```
scoreA    scoreB    scoreC   Final_mean
  50        60        70        60
 ...       ...       ...
```

How to do that in R? How do I work on row for any function. Now, I have mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `rowwise` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(scoreA = 50, scoreB = 60, scoreC = 70)

df %>%#
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(fin_mean = mean(scoreA:scoreC)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  scoreA scoreB scoreC fin_mean
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     50     60     70       60
```

Or you can use Akrun's solution, which is similar but faster:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(fin_mean = select(., scoreA:scoreC) %>% rowMeans)`)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a pretty straightforward way would be to do:

```
df$finalmean <- rowSums(df)/ncol(df)
df
##   scoreA scoreB scoreC finalmean
## 1     50     60     70        60
```

Or just `df$finalmean <- rowMeans(df)`

Comment: Why not `rowMeans`?

Comment: @thela, I was editing that in :-p